# SqlDependency Query Notification error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

I'm trying to get Query Notifications working on SQL Server 2012.  I was following the tutorial at this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach

What I end up with is the OnChange event getting constantly fired.  The SqlNotificationEventArgs says Info=Invalid, Source=Statement, Type=Subscribe.

From my research, I see it's having problems subscribing, but I can't figure out why.  In the SQL Server event logs, all I get is

```
The query notification dialog on conversation handle '{D30D3675-9A2F-E311-A141-8851FB594FAA}.' closed due to the following error: 
'<?xml version="1.0"?><Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error"><Code>-8470</Code><Description>Remote service has been dropped.</Description></Error>'.
```

I've stepped through the common concerns, like making sure I'm using a two part table name, and that my query isn't doing anything forbidden.  Here's the code that sets up the event:

```
 public DataTable RegisterDependency()
 {
     this.CurrentCommand = 
           new SqlCommand("Select CategoryID,CategoryName,Description from dbo.[Categories]", this.CurrentConnection);

     this.CurrentCommand.Notification = null;


     SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(this.CurrentCommand);
     dependency.OnChange += this.dependency_OnChange;

     if (this.CurrentConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
         this.CurrentConnection.Open();

         try
         {
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             dt.Load(this.CurrentCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
             return dt;
         }
         catch { return null; }

}
```

I'm at a loss as to what to check next.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the table definition.  The column "Description" is an 'ntext' type and that doesn't work with notifications.

Comment: @nimdil - sorry, thought I wasn't allowed to do that.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

```
Closed event notification conversation endpoint with handle '{ABC123}', due to the following error: '<?xml version="1.0"?><Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error"><Code>-8470</Code><Description>Remote service has been dropped.</Description></Error>'.
```

I got this error when my `<NotificationService><ConnectionString>` did not match my `<ApplicationService><OnNotification>` database connection values.  (A small typo, but enough to throw it off)